# Wireless driver issue ubuntu 12.04.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

My laptop is relatively new and has Rtl8723be wireless driver. Currently I have ubuntu 12.04.4 with kernel 3.13.0-44-generic. How can I get the wifi to work? Is it a compatibility issue??

Comment: I had exactly same issue, and only solution I found was to update my ubuntu to 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Backports from 3.18 usually work good for Realtek cards, in terminal

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.18.1/backports-3.18.1-1.tar.xz
tar -xf backports-3.18.1-1.tar.xz
cd ~/backports-3.18.1-1
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot when done